# Cannot set position with physicsbody

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have been fiddling with this topic for about three months now. I thought it was just a temporary bug Apple would fix soon and postponed it to the end of development. Now my game is almost finished and I still could not find a good workaround:

If I have a `SKShapeNode` and add a physicsbody to it, I cannot use the `setPosition:(CGPoint)` method to change the position anymore. My object gets always placed at **(0,0)** of its parent view.

I have tried setting the position inside the `didSimulatePhysics` method, to make sure all physic calculation were done.

I tried using `SKAction` to move the node and other suggestions from [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937932/change-position-of-a-skspritenode-that-has-a-physicsbody) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359060/skspritenode-position-changes-to-0-0-for-no-reason) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370597/sknode-position-not-working-always-going-to-default-0-0). None worked as desired.

The only (kind of) working solution for me is to use this workaround method:

```
- (void)setPositionWorkaround:(CGPoint)p {
    CGVector vel = self.physicsBody.velocity;
    CGFloat angVel = self.physicsBody.angularVelocity;
    SKPhysicsBody *temp = self.physicsBody;
    self.physicsBody = nil;

    [self setPosition:p];
    [self setPhysicsBody:temp];
    [self.physicsBody setVelocity:vel];
    [self.physicsBody setAngularVelocity:angVel];
}
```

**Strangely this method works only once.** Every additional time I call this method the position is set to the first call parameter even though there is no data left from the initial call. I checked the parameters and the coordinate systems countless times.

Did someone run into the same problem and found a working solution?

Comment: This is not any apple bug that I am aware of,  are you sure you  have dynamics turned off or turn off affected by gravity?  I wrote a quick sample app and it works fine

Comment: Affected by gravity is off and I tried changing the dynamics flag on / off. Everything worked fine and after an iOS update this behaviour changed on iPhone 6,6+ and iPad. All after the same update. The very same update that messed up SKEmitterNode behaviour for many devs.

Comment: I may need more info then, because I cannot reproduce your bug.  I have a `SKShapeNode` that is a circle,  I slap on a `SKPhysicsBody` that is a circle with the same radius, then I call set position on touch.  Works fine

Comment: I have a rather complicated setup going on inside of the node. I will dissect it and post my results.

Comment: How big is your physics body? Maybe it is much bigger then the ShapeNode. This could cause a collision which prevents your movement. Maybe you can just add a breakpoint in didBeginContact to check

Comment: The physicsbody has half the radius of the ball’s diameter. I removed everything from the ShapeNode and still receive the same behaviour. I will create an empty project and see if I can reproduce it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time fiddling with this problem I finally found the solution for it.

So, since a relatively recent update on SpriteKit (3-4 months back) I cannot move any `SKNode` subclass that has a `SKPhysicsBody` attached to it. `setPosition:(CGPoint)position` and `[SKAction move…]` both do not work.

In my case removing the `SKPhysicsBody` and setting the position did not work, because I was using a pool that recycled my `SKShapeNode`s for performance reasons. The pool did not remove the attached `SKPhysicBodies` though.

So: **If you have this problem make sure ALL `SKPhysicBody` objects are removed from the node and childnodes.**

Comment: This worked, thanks! So frustrating they introduce bugs like this, though.

Comment: @Crashalot Yes, working with Spritekit has been pure pain... I published a blog post about it recently. Hope you are able to finish your project :)

Comment: Indeed, such an unnecessary pain. Forcing a Unity app onto iOS, though, presents its own problems, though.

Comment: Since I'm currently experimenting with Unreal Engine and Unity I would be interested in hearing about the trouble you experience... Any  blog you share it on?

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to suggest we're using Unity ... just sharing experiences from other developers who used Unity and tried to force the game into an Apple app.