# Swift SKSpriteNode Position Issues - logging correct, placement wrong

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, swift

### the situation

I am working through a **[Lynda.com video series (iOS Game Dev. With Sprite Kit)](http://www.lynda.com/iOS-tutorials/iOS-Game-Development-Sprite-Kit/146015-2.html)**, the tutorial is last gen for Objective-C and as a training exercise I am converting it to Swift and playing with new functionality.  The goal is an old school brick breaking game.

I have an updated **[full project repository on GitHub here](https://github.com/josephjaniga/Swift-BrickBreaker)**

### the issue

in the GameScene.swift file, I have written a method `addBricks(size: CGSize)` :

```
func addBricks (size: CGSize){

    println(" the input parameter size: \(size)")

    var maxRows = 1
    var maxCols = 1
    var xPos : CGFloat
    var yPos : CGFloat

    for (var rows = 0; rows < maxRows; rows++){
        for (var i = 0; i < maxCols ; i++){

            var brick: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "brick")
            brick.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: brick.frame.size)

            xPos = CGFloat(size.width) / CGFloat(maxCols+1) * CGFloat(i + 1)
            yPos = CGFloat(size.height) - CGFloat(80 * rows) - 100.0

            brick.physicsBody.dynamic = false
            brick.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = brickCategory

            brick.shadowCastBitMask = 1
            brick.lightingBitMask = 1

            //brick.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(xPos), CGFloat(yPos))
            brick.position = CGPointMake(320.0, 1036.0)

            println("Brick position - xpos: \(xPos), ypos: \(yPos) || overall:\(brick.position)")

            self.addChild(brick)

        }
    }

}
```

I first call it in the scene from `didMoveToView()` and everything is peachy, my brick nodes are placed in the appropriate locations.  In my game logic I later call this method from `didBeginContact()`, when the ball strikes the paddle after a logic check to see there are no bricks left. In the *"When you run out of bricks, add more"* sense...

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!){

    var notTheBall : SKPhysicsBody

    // check the contacts and find the one thats not the ball
    if ( contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask ){
        notTheBall = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        notTheBall = contact.bodyA
    }

    /* more logic here for other contacts */

    if ( notTheBall.categoryBitMask == paddleCategory ){

        self.runAction(playSFXBlip)

        //println("\(self.children.count) and \(staticSize)")

        if ( self.children.count <= 5 ){
            addBricks(self.frame.size)
        }

    }

}
```

On any subsequent method calls to `addBricks()`, ALL of the bricks are placed in what appears to be point 0,0 at the bottom left of the view, even when console is showing they are placed at a different position:

[image]

the self object is the current instance of `SKScene println(self)` -> `<SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {640, 1136}}`

### i've tried:

- casting all elements of my position calculation as `Float`s and `CGFloat`s
- debugging the addBricks method by setting static float values
- making a property for frame size outside of the contact method and passing that size to addBricks.
- google-ing and consulting [the Swift Programming Language Guide](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/id881256329?mt=11) and the docs for anything relevant

what's causing inappropriate positioning? thanks in advance sorry for the `TL;DR`

Comment: in case it matters, i am building for iPhone5s iOS8. but everything else is functionally similar when building for iPhone5

Comment: Who is your contact delegate? The SKScene or some other class?

Comment: @Grimxn, i should be using the SKScene class if i am understanding this correctly `class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate`

Comment: Well, the SKScene class is the obvious delegate, but it's not necessary to be. I asked because in your line "addBricks(self.frame.size)" the "self" is most important. What's the code for addBricks?

Comment: thanks again for the reply, code for add bricks function is posted above and theres a link to a full public repository on github

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that you're trying to set the position of a Node in your didBeginContact method. You cannot position a node in didBeginContact that already has a physicsbody.

The ideal solution would be to add the bricks without a physicsbody, then set it's position to where ever you like, and finally add the physicsbody.

Another solution is to create some code that is being called after you've run your didBeginContact. For example

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!){

    var notTheBall : SKPhysicsBody

    if ( contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask ){
        notTheBall = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        notTheBall = contact.bodyA
    }

    if ( notTheBall.categoryBitMask == paddleCategory ){
        addBricksInUpdate = true
    }
}

func update:(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if (addBricksInUpdate) {
        if ( self.children.count <= 5 ){
            addBricks(self.frame.size)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, and probably addresses our position problem as well. But can you explain why nodes with a physicsBody cannot get positioned inside didBeginContact?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know enough about what "self" is when you are calling, or what self's properties and values are, but when child nodes appear in the bottom left corner it is usually for one of two reasons:

1-The objects have been placed at (0,0) - either because that's their position, or because some other constraint, like size or rect, returned zero values. So you have a parent with size (0,0), or converted coordinates, etc.

[OR]

2- The parent node to the objects is offset/scaled/positioned from the "screen" rect in such a way that the values you are inputting for position on the child have had the children end up looking like they are in the bottom left corner, even though they are actually being placed relative to the parent or the paren't coordinate space. This is easily checked by seeing if different coords still put the object in the same place.

So, check the anchor points for your parent, be it a scene or a node. And check the size and position of the parent. I've heard mention that there are strange default size settings for the sks file in swift with regards to sprite kit and scene size, but haven't opened a swift project yet.

Comment: first thanks for the reply - the self object is the current instance of SKScene `println(self)` -> `<SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {640, 1136}}` - investigating this, because i feel like those ints should be CGfloats

Comment: So, the obvious follow up would be, do the objects appear in the bottom left corner regardless of position you enter? And have you double checked that in each instance they are actually being added to the same parent?

Comment: thanks for the reply - yes any position entered places them at the bottom left, while still logging the position input.  working on finding out how to check the parent they are being added to

Comment: the bricks ARE being added to the same self, but on `println(self)` it appears the brick position is not being set on the subsequent calls `<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'brick' (120 x 60)] position:{0, 0} size:{60, 30} rotation:0.00]`... so the question is why does `addBricks()` set position on the first call

Comment: Ah, well that's easier to debug, because now we are using option 1 in my answer, instead of option 2. But in your initial question you were saying that the bricks were reporting a position of (320,1036), but showing at (0,0), is that no longer the case? They are at (0,0) and reporting as being at (0,0)?

Comment: first method call is placing the brick appropriately and logs accurate position, second method call logs the intended position, but places the brick at 0,0 - third method call logs 0,0... sensing a failure in logic here trying to find it.. console output gist here https://gist.github.com/josephjaniga/2b05b6236fdbf8ec039c

Comment: found it! you must define a position before assigning a physics body else you cannot reposition the SKNode  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20359622/2397883