# Child Node Positioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working on a game with a primary player as an SKSpriteNode. The game has a concept of powerups that can be acquired, and each player can have a set of attachments.

I have a protocol for attachments defined as:

```
@protocol ESPlayerAttachment <NSObject>

@required

-(ESPlayerAttachmentType)attachmentType;

@optional

-(void)willAttachToPlayer:(ESPlayerSpriteNode *)player;
-(void)didDetachFromPlayer:(ESPlayerSpriteNode *)player;
-(void)player:(ESPlayerSpriteNode *)player willUseAttachmentInParent:(SKNode *)parent;

@end
```

Additionally, I have a protocl for powerups defined as:

```
@protocol ESPlayerPowerup <NSObject>

-(void)acquiredByPlayer:(ESPlayerSpriteNode *)player;

@end
```

Finally, I have a physics body on the power up box, as well as one on the player so that I can detect the collision and attach the powerup. As an example, I have a shield powerup that is implemented as:

```
-(void)willAttachToPlayer:(ESPlayerSpriteNode *)player
{
    [player detachAttachmentsOfType:ESPlayerAttachmentTypeShield];
    __weak ESPlayerShipSpriteNode *weakPlayer = player;
    [player.parent addChild:_shield];
    _shield.position = CGPointMake(player.position.x, player.position.y + 0.1f * _shield.size.height);
    [self performSelector:@selector(detachFromPlayer:) withObject:weakPlayer afterDelay:15.0f];
}
```

What's bothering me is that if I attach the shield powerup to the player in my SKScene class (in the `update` or `didMoveToView` methods), everything works. The shield is positioned correctly. However, if I add it through the `ESPlayerPowerup` method (which gets called during a collision with the player), the node gets positioned relative to `SKScene`, so it ends up in the bottom left corner of the screen. I can't seem to figure out what the difference is (there's only one instance of ESPlayerSpriteNode in the game, so I'm relatively confident that isn't the problem)

Comment: [player.parent addChild:_shield] - You add the shield node to the player's parent node (SKScene node ?), is that on purpose ?

Comment: @giorashc Yeah, the player is an SKSpriteNode contained within a SKNode (the parent isn't SKScene). The reason for this is that I need the attachments (the shield in this case) to share a common parent with the player.

Comment: I don't see some of the code you mention, but I can only assume it's because you're dealing with different coordinate systems depending on what object is attempting to position the shield, and what object the shield is parented to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I ended up finding this post on SO, which has solved my problem:

[SKSPriteNode position changes to 0,0 for no reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359060/skspritenode-position-changes-to-0-0-for-no-reason/20359622#comment33295726_20359622)

It would seem to be a bug in SpriteKit, but positioning the item before attaching the physicsBody does work, and positions it correctly.